# Laravel 5.11 Composer Update Error

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

The oriceon-oauth-5-laravel package was installed by my friend and I pulled the code from git. I run the command composer update, but it throws the following error

**exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException'** with message **'Class 'Artdarek\OAuth\OAuthServiceProvider' not found'** in **/var/www/html/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:146**

I resolved this temporarily by commenting the **service providers** and **aliases** in **app.php** file.

So,what is the correct way to resolve this issue. Its happening after installing the packages in laravel 5.11

Comment: Have you tried to separate minimal code example in order to be able to show actual code causing the problem?

Comment: No I didnt. I am getting this error whenever ui do composer update new package is installed by other persons.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, in your `config/app.php` file, you'll probably see this:

```
Artdarek\OAuth\OAuthServiceProvider::class,
```

in the list of providers. Since you haven't yet installed that package, the class doesn't exist. I think you figured that part out since you said you commented out the providers.

In `composer.json` you'll see under scripts:

```
"pre-update-cmd": [
    "php artisan clear-compiled"
],
```

That means that whenever you run `composer update`, it first calls `php artisan clear-compiled`, which loads your config files, which fails because of that missing class.

Two ways to get around it:

Change the provider to be a quote in strings like they were in Laravel 4:

```
"Artdarek\OAuth\OAuthServiceProvider",
```

(that's why nobody really had this problem until Laravel 5 / [PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php)). Or...

**Real solution**

Just run `composer install` instead of `composer update`. That's what you should be doing anyway, because whatever your teammate pushed was working with the versions of the libraries that are in `composer.lock`. So if you run install, it's a) installing known working versions and b) bypassing that `php artisan` command until after the install is finished.

If you really must run `composer update`, then use it with the `--no-scripts` flag

Comment: I did composer update --no-scripts.. It worked.. Is that best practice??

Comment: @karthick when working with a team, ideally any time your teammate installs or updates a package, they should run all tests before pushing. Then when you pull, the composer.lock file has the exact version #s that your teammate used. When you run `composer install` it installs those exact versions. If you run `composer update` then instead it looks for the latest version and could break things. So `composer install` is best practice unless you are intentionally upgrading libraries